# Get Uri from Bitmap returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm getting Runtime Exception while getting Uri from Bitmap. **BTW the same code works perfect in standalone project**.

Call to Camera intent

```
private void openCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
            REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
}




 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        String s = getImageUri(photo).toString();
        Globals.saveImagePathToSharedPref(getActivity(), s);
        setImage(Uri.parse(s));

    }

}

public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

In getImageUri method, the path is returning null, and the exception as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, 
     request=327780, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }}
     to activity : java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) as an extra to the `cameraIntent`, the full sized image will then be saved to that location. The bitmap returned in the intent activity result is just a thumbnail.

You can use 
`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

To generate the `Uri` to pass in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getImageUri()` method is poorly named, because it does more than get an Uri, it also saves the image to storage first (which is arguably the more important operation).

Look at the [docs for `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(…)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> **Returns**
>
> The URL to the newly created image, or null if the image failed to be stored for any reason.

So that's (likely) the reason why you get a `null` path back and your code explodes.

There's nothing you can do to guarantee that saving the image always succeeds (e.g. the flash memory may be full), so you'll have to modify your code to recover from this error case, e.g. by telling the user that their image could not be saved.